# title, content, feature images

Tags: customization, themes, twitter-bootstrap

in my testimonials section the title, and content do not show. the feature images show with extra image attached to each one.  I'm new to php and word press. using WP 4.9 (here is my code)

```
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <h2>What People Are Saying About Brad</h2>
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>  

    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<div class="row testimonial">
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
               the_post_thumbnail( array() );
           }    
        ?>

        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/assets/img/brennan.jpg" alt="Brennan">
    </div><!-- end col -->
    <div class="col-sm-8">                          

        <blockquote>
            <?php the_content; ?>
            <cite>&mdash;<?php the_title; ?></cite>
        </blockquote>

    </div><!-- end col -->

</div><!-- row -->                  
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: the functions for the title and the content are in your posted code; the problem might be formatting or some other influences which could be too localized for the forum to help.

Answer (score 1):

your code in some minor error. you can not write 'the_content' like this.
this is a function. your are missing brackets.

your code:

```
<?php the_title; ?>
<?php the_content; ?>
```

Replace with this:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

AND for image 'the_post_thumbnail()' remove argument array. and check it For more detail: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: If answer is useful then accept this so it's useful for other.